# Image flickering when I auto-refresh the component ( Ionic angular )

Tags: ionic-framework

For my app requires auto-refresh for every 5 sec. I have implemented in Ionic with angular. Initial page is loading the image URL ,but when I refresh the page automatically ,image is loading but it is flickering and again it is flickering after 5 sec and it is repeating for every 5 sec. but in android it is working fine flickering is not happening for every 5 sec image is replacing with new image or existing image without flickering. but for IOS only when I’m trying to refresh it is flickering.

example code:
**1. Html file: tab1.page.html**

```
<ion-grid class="dashgrid" *ngIf="roomApp != 0">

  <div class="col-12">

    <div class="row">

      <div *ngFor="let item of roomApp">

        <div class="box" style="width:155px;" [ngClass]="{

              'redBorder':item.current_status == 0,

              'greenBorder':item.current_status == 1,

              'amberBorder':item.current_status == 2

            }">

          <div class="text-right">

            <ion-icon (click)="editName(item.id,item.custom_appliance_name);" name="create"></ion-icon>

          </div>

          <p *ngIf="!item.custom_appliance_name" class='data font12 hometitle'>{{item.appliance_name}}</p>

          <p *ngIf="item.custom_appliance_name" class='data font12 hometitle'>{{item.custom_appliance_name}}</p>

          <img src="{{item.off_icon}}" *ngIf="item.current_status == 0" alt="" class="cardimg" />

          <img src="{{item.on_icon}}" *ngIf="item.current_status == 1" alt="" class="cardimg" />

          <img src="{{item.off_icon}}" *ngIf="item.current_status == 2" alt="" class="cardimg" />

          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

            <div *ngIf="item.current_status == 1 || item.current_status == 0">

              <ion-toggle color="primary" style="padding-bottom: 4px;"

                (click)="checkStatus(item.id,item.current_status)"

                [checked]="item.current_status == 1 ? 'true' : 'false'"></ion-toggle>

              <div *ngIf="item.current_status == 1" class="font10">On</div>

              <div *ngIf="item.current_status == 0" class="font10">Off</div>

            </div>

            <div *ngIf="item.current_status == 2" class="d-flex align-items-center">

              <div *ngIf="item.current_status == 2" class="font10 p-2"

                style="background-color:red; color:#fff;border-radius:6px;">FAULTY</div>

            </div>

            <div>

              <ion-toggle class="custom-toggle" (click)="checkNotification(item.id,item.notification_status)"

                [checked]="item.notification_status == 1 ? 'true' : 'false'" style="padding-bottom: 4px;">

              </ion-toggle>

              <div class="font10">Notification</div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</ion-grid>

<ion-grid *ngIf="roomApp== 0" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center red">

  No Appliances found

</ion-grid>
```

**2. TS file: tab1.page.ts**

```
doRefresh() {
this.apiService.rooms(this.uid).subscribe(response => {
if (!response[‘error’]) {
localStorage.setItem(“appliances”, JSON.stringify(response[‘appliances’]));
this.allAppliance = response[‘appliances’];
this.roomApp = this.allAppliance[this.room_id];
}
else {
this.resError = response[‘error’];
}
},
(err) => {
console.log("error==> ", err);
if (err[‘status’] == 401) {
this.navController.navigateForward(’/login’);
localStorage.setItem(‘loginValue’, ‘logout’);
}
})
}
```

**3. scss file: tab1.page.scss**

```
ion-content ion-toolbar {
–background: transparent;
}
.box {
box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(var(–ion-color-dark-rgb), 0.24);
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
padding: 6px;
min-height: 190px;
}
.cardimg {
width: 84px;
height: 84px;
}
.data {
margin: 0;
}
.font12{
font-size:12px;
}
.font10{
font-size:10px;
}
.red{
color:gray;
height: 100vh;
}
.greenBorder{
border-bottom:4px solid green;
}
.redBorder{
border-bottom:4px solid gray;
}
.amberBorder{
border-bottom:4px solid red;
}
.loading{
background-color:transparent !important;
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vidut",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/preview-any-file": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "6.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "highcharts": "^8.1.0",
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.29",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^7.7.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-preview-any-file": "^0.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-preview-any-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

**In Android it is working fine without flickering below you can see Gif.**
**In IOS it is not working ,it is flickering**
can anyone help me from this issue

Comment: For iOS are you using the latest webview toolkit? Could you post your package.json?

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for your reply

just now i have added package.json file .please find there.

Comment: For getting an / what exactly the issue is you can check this link : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/image-flickering-when-i-auto-refresh-the-component/204827?u=thotashivakumar 

In link i have provided GIF files of both IOS and Android.